# Accessing axios body parameter outside the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, axios

I have this axios request:

```
 axios.all([

    axios.post(baseURL+'sentiments', {
      sentiment_type: 'positive',
      filter_tab: type
    }),

    axios.post(baseURL+'sentiments', {
      sentiment_type: 'negative',
      filter_tab: type
    })
])
    .then(axios.spread(result1, result2) => { 
          console.log(result1),
          console.log(result2)
    })
    .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
    })
```

Then in my render method, 
What I am trying to achieve is to access 'sentiment_type' value 'positive' into some variable or something, to further use it for conditional rendering.

```
if(sentiment_type === positive){ 
   then do this
 }
else{ 
      do something else
    }
```

Is there any way to do this? Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this part of code, is part of a component. 
You could store these variables in a local store. 
Here is a link for more information: [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

and an example, I hope this will help you.

```
    class parentComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sentiment_types: [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.post(baseURL+'sentiments', {
              sentiment_type: 'positive',
              filter_tab: type
    })
    .then((firstResponse) => { 
            axios.post(baseURL+'sentiments', {
                sentiment_type: 'negative',
                  filter_tab: type
            })
            .then((secondResponse) => {
                // Here you can store you results into the state
                this.setState({
                    sentiment_types: ['positive', 'negative'];
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })          
          console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
    })
  }

  render() {
   <childComponent sentiment_types={this.state.sentiment_types} />
  }
}

const childComponent = (props) => {
    if(props.state.sentiment_types.includes('positive')){
        return <h1>oke</h1>
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes It is my parent component. On the basis of this, I want to pass props further without having to write three different types

Comment: I hope the changes are useful. Now the state is passed to the childComponent (I did not test this code, it has been a while programming React haha)

Comment: Thanks for the demo. This might help me. One more thing, What if there are two different sentiment types: positive and negative? Then how I am supposed to handle it?. Like If need to send two axios request on positive and negative and then further use them for conditional redndering?

Comment: It depends on when and how you want to fire the request. I assume that you mean that you fire a new Request after the first one. You can chain these axios requests. Is this what you ment? I can edit the code sample if so.

Comment: I tried chaining axios and updated my code. Please Check it. Now on the basis of this updated one, and yours answer, How can I check condition between positive or negative and then render?

Comment: That is not what I ment with chaining :), I will update my answer

Comment: Just one typo confirmation. This `sentiment_types = ['positive', 'negative']` should be `sentiment_types: ['positive', 'negative']` in setState() ??